# Trying to configure gitlab to skip the CI pipeline on MERGE REQUESTS and COMMITS when a file in a subfolder is modified

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

I've tried adding an `except:  changes: - docs/**` to the .gitlab-ci.yaml file, but it runs anyway.

Yes, I committed and pushed the change to the yaml file and it ran the pipeline, which I expected it to.

But when I changed a file in the docs folder, the pipeline ran again. I thought the except changes would make it skip that.

So to summarize. I DO NOT want the pipeline to run on MERGE REQUESTS or COMMITS when a file is modified in or under the docs folder.

Answer (score 0):

If your pipeline has few stages you'd need to add the `except` bit to every one of those.

Easier way to achieve this is to base all of them on an [anchor](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors):

```
.common-setup: &common-setup-template
  except:  
    changes: 
    - docs/**

any-stage:
    <<: *common-setup-template
    stage: any-stage
    ...
```